# Create Password for already existing xls File

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am getting below exception while running.Need to protect xls file which is already exists.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: no such entry: "EncryptionInfo", had:
>   []    at
>   org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DirectoryNode.getEntry(DirectoryNode.java:399)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DirectoryNode.createDocumentInputStream(DirectoryNode.java:188)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo.(EncryptionInfo.java:94)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo.(EncryptionInfo.java:76)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageAccess;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionMode;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.Encryptor;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;

public class xlsProtect {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem();
            EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(fs);
            Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();
            enc.confirmPassword("test"); // s3cr3t is your password to open sheet.

            OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open(new File("C:/Users/test/Desktop/pdf/1.xls"), PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);
            OutputStream os = enc.getDataStream(fs);
            opc.save(os);
            opc.close();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/test/Desktop/pdf/1.xls");
            fs.writeFilesystem(fos);
            fos.close();

            fs.writeFilesystem(fos);
            fos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try following https://poi.apache.org/encryption.html#XML-based+formats+-+Encryption ?

Comment: Yes tried, but not working below exception occur org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationException: Can't open the specified file input stream from file: 'C:\Users\test\Desktop\pdf\1.xls'
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.openZipEntrySourceStream(ZipPackage.java:155)

Comment: You can't open a `XLS` file with OPC, OPC is for the newer `XLSX` only. You need to convert your input file to match, or do XLS-only stuff

Comment: Thank you very much ! it works for XLSX ,but not for xls. May i know whether any way we can make xls file as a password protected one

Comment: Did you follow https://poi.apache.org/encryption.html#Binary+formats ?

Comment: @Gagravarr , I tried, but not working. xls file is opening without password. try {
            Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword("pass");
            NPOIFSFileSystem fs = new NPOIFSFileSystem(new File("C:/Users/test/Desktop/pdf/1.xls"), true);
            HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs.getRoot(), true);
            Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword()` method has to be called after you've opened a .xls. See the following for encrypting both formats.
I've tested the .xls with Excel 2016 and Libre Office 6.0 - Libre Office currently can't open CryptoAPI encrypted files - if this is an issue for you, I think the example can be adapted to fallback to Binary RC4 encryption.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;

import org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.record.crypto.Biff8EncryptionKey;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionMode;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.Encryptor;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class EncryptTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        encryptHSSF();
        encryptXSSF();

        for (final String file : new String[] {"test.xls","test.xlsx"}) {
            try (Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(file), "pass")) {
                System.out.println(wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void encryptHSSF() throws IOException, EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException {
        generateFile("test.xls");

        try (HSSFWorkbook hwb = (HSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(new File("test.xls"))) {
            Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword("pass");
            hwb.write();
        }
    }

    public static void encryptXSSF() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        generateFile("test.xlsx");

        try (POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem()) {
            EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.agile);
            Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();
            enc.confirmPassword("pass");

            try (OutputStream os = enc.getDataStream(fs)) {
                try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("test.xlsx")) {
                    IOUtils.copy(is, os);
                }
            }

            try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.xlsx")) {
                fs.writeFilesystem(fos);
            }
        }
    }


    public static void generateFile(final String filename) throws IOException {
        try (Workbook wb = filename.endsWith("x") ? new XSSFWorkbook() : new HSSFWorkbook()) {
            wb.createSheet("test").createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("Test");
            try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename)) {
                wb.write(fos);
            }
        }
    }
}
```